# Understanding disassembly - Seeing two main()'s

Tags: c, assembly, disassembly

The dump of the following C program:

```
int main() {
    int i,j;
    for(i=0; i<2; i++) {
        j++;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

is producing:

```
08048394 <main>:
int main() {
 8048394:   8d 4c 24 04             lea    0x4(%esp),%ecx
 8048398:   83 e4 f0                and    $0xfffffff0,%esp
 804839b:   ff 71 fc                pushl  -0x4(%ecx)
 804839e:   55                      push   %ebp
 804839f:   89 e5                   mov    %esp,%ebp
 80483a1:   51                      push   %ecx
 80483a2:   83 ec 10                sub    $0x10,%esp
    int i,j;
    for(i=0; i<2; i++) {
 80483a5:   c7 45 f8 00 00 00 00    movl   $0x0,-0x8(%ebp)
 80483ac:   eb 08                   jmp    80483b6 <main+0x22>
        j++;
 80483ae:   83 45 f4 01             addl   $0x1,-0xc(%ebp)
int main() {
    int i,j;
    for(i=0; i<2; i++) {
 80483b2:   83 45 f8 01             addl   $0x1,-0x8(%ebp)
 80483b6:   83 7d f8 01             cmpl   $0x1,-0x8(%ebp)
 80483ba:   7e f2                   jle    80483ae <main+0x1a>
        j++;
    }
    return 0;
 80483bc:   b8 00 00 00 00          mov    $0x0,%eax
}
```

No matter whether I put `i<2` or `i<10`, I am seeing two `main()`'s with the same structure. Can someone tell me why this is happening?

Answer (score 2):

You are not seeing two `main()`s.  You are seeing a disassembler utterly confused out of its mind by a `for` loop.  The actual assembly, if you read it all the way through, represents exactly one function, `main()`, and the logic path is identical to the C code.

In short: the C interleaved into the assembly is **wrong**.

Comment: Oh! Then could you please tell me what these are doing: `jmp    80483b6 <main+0x22>` and `jle    80483ae <main+0x1a>`? And finally, is there a way to improve this disassembly?

Comment: I wouldn't fault the disassembler, the disassembly looks fine; it's just parroting the debug information in the object file, which contains a mapping from source file:line to output, and is not always accurate.

Comment: @Legend: The `jmp` is jumping from the for loop`s initialization code (`i=0`) to the test (`i<2`).  The `jle` is a jump-if-less-than-or-equal-to, which is comparing `i` to `1` (`i<2` was optimized to `i<=1` by the compiler).  If it is less than or equal to 1, control is transferred to the body of the for loop.

Answer (score 2):

The disassembler is dutifully interleaving the source code exactly as the compiler's output debug information says.  On Linux, you can see this with `objdump -W`:

```
…
 Line Number Statements:
  Extended opcode 2: set Address to 0x80483e4
  Copy
  Special opcode 91: advance Address by 6 to 0x80483ea and Line by 2 to 3
  Special opcode 132: advance Address by 9 to 0x80483f3 and Line by 1 to 4
  Special opcode 60: advance Address by 4 to 0x80483f7 and Line by -1 to 3
  Special opcode 148: advance Address by 10 to 0x8048401 and Line by 3 to 6
  Special opcode 76: advance Address by 5 to 0x8048406 and Line by 1 to 7
  Advance PC by 2 to 0x8048408
  Extended opcode 1: End of Sequence
…
```

My compiler apparently differs a bit from yours, as the addresses are different, but you see how it works: the mapping between addresses in the output assembly and lines in the input source file is imprecise.